# AWS Elastic Beanstalk . Execute .ebextensions commands only on new Instance or Manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have configured my .ebextensions folder to download and install a windows service on the leader ec2 instance. 
Problem is that every time i want to update to a new version of the web application (Not the windows service) Those commands execute again and try to re install the service again.

On the other side. Every time i want to update only the widows service, i have to do the work manually through ssh or rdp. Or re-deploy the whole application which triggers the .ebextensions commands.

Is there a more elegant workflow for this i am skipping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering Elastic Beanstalk weakest link. You host two different services on the same EB instance, which is unsupported by EB (which is lame I agree).
I resolved the "setup only once" need by appending a test to the setup extentension config file. In my case it's a linux box, but you can do something similar:

```
commands:
    10_setup_win_service:
        test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.post-provisioning-complete
        command: <...>
```

Now to complete this hack I have a file called `.ebextensions/99_finalize_setup.config`:

```
commands:
  99_write_post_provisioning_complete_file:
    command: touch /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.post-provisioning-complete
```

this approach ensures the win service is installed only once.

Now for your maintenance issue of the win service, you cannot use the EB toolset for that. Your understanding of the options here are correct - either use SSH to automate the work, or do it manually by logging into the server.